# How to serialize an NSArray to JSON using JSONModel

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, jsonmodel

Strangely, there doesn't appear to be any public method to serialize an array, yet it can obviously do it when serializing an array *property*. I have a JSONModel-inherited class with an array property. I want to get a JSON textual representation of just that property, not the whole object.

I don't mind modifying the source, but a head-start as to where to look would be appreciated.

Another thought is to serialize each object individually to JSON and wrap them in `[`,`]`.

Comment: What is JSONModel? Are you using NSJSONSerialization?

Comment: Is it this? https://github.com/icanzilb/JSONModel

Comment: I think I will just write my own category to do it manually and be done with it.

Comment: Maybe because an array is not an JSONModel subclass and `modelWithIndexValue` in the NSArray category doesn't seem to do what you are looking for?

Comment: care to select an answer?

Comment: care to select an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Explanation:**

JSONModel model represents a JSON object - it matches JSON keys to a model class's properties. That's why for examples you cannot directly create a JSONModel class that matches a JSON feed whose top object is an array. For example:

> [obj1, obj2, obj3, etc ...]

There's just no key to match to a property.

Now what you are asking about is the same situation, but in reverse. You cannot export an NSArray to JSON, because there's no JSONModel to take care of it. If you have a model with one property, which is an NSArray - then it's easy. The property will get mapped to 1 JSON key and the NSArray contents will get exported as its contents.

**Solution:**

If you have an NSArray containing JSONModel instances, you should use the following method:

```
NSArray* jsonObjects = [YourModelClass arrayOfDictionariesFromModels: modelObjects];
```

The line above will take care to properly export model classes to dictionaries, then you can export jsonObjects to JSON by using [NSJSONSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/foundation/reference/nsjsonserialization_class/Reference/Reference.html).

Here's the method's docs:

http://www.jsonmodel.com/docs/Classes/JSONModel.html#//api/name/arrayOfDictionariesFromModels:

Comment: any full example of how to use this?

Answer (score 4):

It ended up actually being pretty easy to implement myself. Very strange this isn't just included in the library though:

```
@implementation NSArray (JSONModelExtensions)

- (NSString*)toJSONString {
    NSMutableArray* jsonObjects = [NSMutableArray new];
    for ( id obj in self )
        [jsonObjects addObject:[obj toJSONString]];
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"[%@]", [jsonObjects componentsJoinedByString:@","]];
}

@end
```

Comment: @MobileMon This is the implementation of a category on `NSArray` called NSArray+JSONModelExtensions.m. You'll also need a corresponding NSArray+JSONModelExtensions.h and to #import the .h in any files that want to use this method (or import it in your project's precompiled header to be accessible anywhere within the project). Research Objective-C categories for more.

Comment: yeah I figured but this only works for an object with 1 array. Now if each of those arrays have arrays, this fails. I ended up just creating a bunch of dictionaries myself and using NSJSONSerialization

Comment: @MobileMon Actually it should work recursively. What sort of failure are you seeing?

Answer (score 1):

Serialization (objects to json text):

```
NSArray* jsonString = [YourObject arrayOfDictionariesFromModels: yourobjectsArray];
```

If u dont want a warning u have to give NSArray type to jsonString but it will be a simple JSON so it can be NSString too.

Deserialization: (json text back to objects):

```
NSArray* objectsAgain = [YourObject arrayOfModelsFromDictionaries: jsonString];
```

Note that the jsonString given is the same that we got at serialization.